# A new piece of clue for document classification?

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I am working on a document classification problem. I am using a document term vector to represent each document. If document has some term, the vector entry for that term is 1.

But with the training data, I can get a piece of information which I think may be useful. It is the term popularity within each category respectively. It is defined as below:

Popularity (term T, category X) = (documents belonging to X containing T)/ (total documents belonging to X)

This is calculated with the training set.

I believe this value can be interpreted as the **representability** of a term for a certain category, which in other words, is the term's popularity within a certain category.

I have a feeling that it could somehow influence the vector weight for a term. But I haven't figured out a reasonable way to use it. If I want to use this popularity value for a new document to be classified, I need to know its category first (or do I?). This is kind of a dilemma.

Could anyone shed some light? Could this value be helpful in the classification?

Answer (score 0):

The "representability" is known in NLP as "document frequency" and is a standard way of term weighting. The more sophisticated (yet still trivial) method is so called "tf-idf" weighting. It is (in most cases) much better approach than your current set of words representation.

Comment: My original approach is to represent doc-term vector as 0/1 bit vector based on the term existence in the document. As I tried, it performs comparably as good as the tf*idf approach. My point is, can I utilize the *term popularity* in my question in some way? It doesn't *relate term to document*, but *relates term to category*.